# reload page and go to previously active tab php jquery-jtable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-jtable

I want to reload the page and navigate to the user's previously active tab after the user has clicked the `submit` button on a `jquery-jtable` form. What I have now reloads the page but doesn't navigate to the user's last active tab before the reload. The tabs are created using `jquery ui`. Here's the shortened html:

```
    <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#tabs-TasksWithRisks'>Tasks With Risks</a></li>
                <li><a href='#tabs-Lessons-Learned'>Lessons Learned</a></li>
            </ul>

           <div id='tabs-TasksWithRisks' class='tab'>
                <div id="TasksWithRisksTableContainer" class="jTableContainer" style="width:100%;"></div>
            </div>
            <div id='tabs-Lessons-Learned' class='tab'>
                <div id="LessonsLearnedTableContainer" class="jTableContainer" style="width:100%;"></div>
            </div>            
     </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var project_id = <?php echo $project_data['project_id']; ?>;
    var modify = <?php echo $modify ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        loadViewProjectTasksWithRisksTable('TasksWithRisksTableContainer', project_id, modify);
        loadViewLessonsLearnedTable('LessonsLearnedTableContainer', project_id, modify);
</script>
```

---

```
function loadViewLessonsLearnedTable(ContainerID, project_id, modify, no_toolbar) {
    var fields = $.extend(true, fields, LessonsLearnedFields); //copy, don't reference
    fields.Responses = getLessonsLearnedResponseChildTable(ContainerID);
    $('#' + ContainerID).jtable({
        title: 'Lessons Learned',
        paging: true,
        pageSize: 100,
        sorting: true,
        defaultSorting: 'WBS ASC',
        actions: {
            listAction: config.base_url + 'data_fetch/risks_cause_by_project/' + project_id,
            deleteAction: config.base_url + 'data_fetch/delete_risk/',
            updateAction: config.base_url + 'data_fetch/update_lessons_learned_risk/' + project_id 
        },
        messages: defaultRiskMessages,
        fields: fields,        ,
        formSubmitting: function(event,data){
            $('select[name=cause]', data.form).attr('name','cause[]');
            location.reload(true);
            return data;
        }
    });
    $('#' + ContainerID).jtable('load');
}
```

I tired `location.href = config.base_url + '#tabs-Lessons-Learned';` but that didn't work. Most working solutions that I found online were for bootstrap so they weren't of much help.

I found [this question on stackoveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421669/set-jquery-ui-active-tab-on-page-load-reload) but I wasn't able to tailor the answer to my needs.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `location.reload(true);` I used `loaction.assign('address_I_wanted_to_go_to')`