# focus on the same tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I'm using jquery UI to create tabs. Requirement is when i select tab2 or any other tab and reload/refresh the page, focus should be on the selected tab. Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CnEUh/500/

I have gone through many online forums but could not get the expected result.
I followed the link [Set Jquery ui active tab on page load/reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421669/set-jquery-ui-active-tab-on-page-load-reload) , but didn't got the result.

Tried the below code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs({active: tabs-2});
      // Set active tab on page load
      var  SelectedTab = tabs-2;
     if(tabSelectedId!=""){
       $("#tabs").tabs({selected: tabSelectedId});
      }  
  });
```

Please suggest how can i keep the focus on the selected tab on page reload. My fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CnEUh/500/

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it by using location.href

On click, just add #tab=2 and then on page load, here you can retrieve location.href and choose which tav is selected.

Comment: can you please provide any example or link so that i can follow. My trial :  http://jsfiddle.net/CnEUh/500/  ,thanks @Sheremet.

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery.cookie.js library and the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            activate: function(event ,ui){
                $.cookie('active_tab', ui.newTab.index(), { path: '/' });
            }
        });
        var selectedIndex=parseInt($.cookie('active_tab'));
        if(selectedIndex) {
            $tabs.tabs({ active: selectedIndex });
            $('#tabs').find("ul:first li:nth-child(" + (selectedIndex + 1) + ")").find('a').trigger('click');
        }
        // set cookie on tab select
});
```

Or without jquery.cookie.js, pass the active tab index as a parameter

```
var activeTab;
var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        activeTab = ui.newTab.index();
    }
});

var params = {};

if (location.search) {
    var parts = location.search.substring(1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var nv = parts[i].split('=');
        if (!nv[0]) continue;
        params[nv[0]] = nv[1] || true;
    }
}

// Now you can get the parameters you want like so:
var selectedIndex = parseInt(params.selectedIndex);
if (selectedIndex) {
    $tabs.tabs({
        active: selectedIndex
    });
    $('#tabs').find("ul:first li:nth-child(" + (selectedIndex + 1) + ")").find('a').trigger('click');
}

$('#tabs').click(function() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace( /[\?#].*|$/, "?selectedIndex="+activeTab );
});
```

Hopefully it works.
Thanks

Comment: Can we do without use of cookies, as i cannot add extra libraries. Please suggest if possible, thanks. @Biswas.