# Jquery Tabs - return selected tab dynamically

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

On page load I would like to display selected tab dynamically. This is so validation is displayed for the correct tab. I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var selectedTabId= $("#SelectedTab").val();
        alert(selectedTabId);

        $('#tabs').tabs(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
                selectedTabId = ui.newPanel.attr('id');
                $("#SelectedTab").val(selectedTabId);
            },
            selected: selectedTabId
        })

    });
</script>
```

The selected tab is correct which is set in a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.SelectedTab" id="SelectedTab" name="SelectedTab" />
```

I have tried numerous options from links on stackoverflow and can't get the slected tab to display.
[Stackoverflow:selecting & loading a jquery tab programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970838/selecting-loading-a-jquery-tab-programatically)

[Stackoverflow: Set Jquery ui active tab on page load/reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421669/set-jquery-ui-active-tab-on-page-load-reload)

```
$("#tabs").tabs('select', selectedTabId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work, not sure if best approach.

```
$("#tabs").tabs(
{
  active: $("#SelectedTabToFind").val(),
  cache: false
});
```

I set the value of SelectedTabToFind in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

`selected` was deprecated as of 1.9 and is now replaced by `active`, try:

**As discovered in comments, you need to specify the `index` of the tab to select NOT the ID**:

```
$('#tabs').tabs(
    {
        cache: false,
        beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
            selectedTabId = ui.newPanel.index();
            $("#SelectedTab").val(selectedTabId);
        },
        active: selectedTabId
    })
```

Make sure the `selectedTabId` is the zero-based index.

Comment: Thanks @mattytommo selectedTabId value is tabs-1 or tabs-2. Could you explain 'Make sure the selectedTabId is the zero-based index'?

Comment: @Ros Ahhhhh, it must be a number, so 0 would be the first tab, 1 would be the second etc.

Comment: @Ros So you'd have to do `selectedTabId.replace("tabs-", "")` providing your first tab is tabs-0. If your first tab is tabs-1 then you'd have to do `parseInt(selectedTabId.replace("tabs-", "")) - 1`

Comment: @Ros Check my update, instead of using `ui.newPanel.attr("id")` you can simply use `ui.newPanel.index()`, no other code changes required.

Comment: its working, but if I do a second submit with the same tab open it defaults back to the first tab index of 0.

Comment: @Ros If you stick your alert in on page load is the correct tab index stored in the variable?

Comment: on page load its 0 and when I do a submit the variable is set to 2?

Comment: @Ros I think I know the problem, your updated model won't be reflected when you return the view after a submit (as MVC relies on the PRG pattern). In your scenario, you'll have to do `ModelState.Remove("SelectedTab")` in order for the updated value to be sent back to the view after a submit.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why the index jumps from 0 to 2, I expected the next index to be 1