# Active tab background gets changed on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried this code to change the `background-color` of `li` tag on click. It is changing the `background-color` when we `:hover` or click but when it navigates to the page it does not remain the same, it displays to default color.
Basically I want an active tab background color, but I as I have mentioned it gets back to its default color on page refresh(reload).

Please advice.

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready( function(){
          $('.nan_canada').on('click','.menuil',function () {
             $(this).addClass('selected')
          });
      });
  </script>

 <div class="nan_canada">
     <ul >
        <li class="menuil" ><a href="a.php">Resume Template & LinkedIn Podcasts</a></li>
        <li class="menuil"><a href="jas.php" >Job Postings </a></li>
        <li class="menuil"><a href="a.php">   Search Firms</a></li>
        <li class="menuil"><a href="aj.php" target="_blank"> nav</a></li>
        <li class="menuil"><a href="books.php">Book List </a></li>
        <li class="menuil"><a href="#"> Order Free Book </a></li>            
        <strong><font size="4" style="float:right; padding-right:10px;"><a href="at.php" style="color:#fff;">Log Out</a></font></strong> </ul>
    </div>

    <style type="text/css">
        .menuil {
               color:#000000;
         }
        .menuil  #selected_step_box, 
        .QuickStartLong:hover {
               background-color: #fff; !important
         }
         .selected {
               background-color : #fff;
         }
     </style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Jquery ui active tab on page load/reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421669/set-jquery-ui-active-tab-on-page-load-reload)

Answer (score 0):

Actually its because redirection, when you click to link its redirect you to a new page.And every time script loaded from starting. One thing you can do(as per my knowledge) .

Put a unique id to every list item,Some thing like this.

```
    <li class="menuil" id='l1'><a href="a.php">Resume Template & LinkedIn Podcasts</a></li>
                                                    .
                                                    .
                                                    .
```

Create a js file and include this to all list pages.

```
var page = $(location).attr('href');//use string function to get page name

switch(page)
{
  case 'youpage1':
    $('#l1').addClass('selected');
    break;
   case 'youpage2':
    $('#l2').addClass('selected');
    break;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Edited Answer,,, this one is exactly what you want right??

Comment: i want something like this but somehow its not working!

Comment: did you changed the `id` and include the file to all linked pages.

Comment: try to alert the `page` and check if there is any case of that.. and post your new code so i can help you.